# Accessing S3 bucket from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to write to S3 bucket from a Lambda function after setting up the required permissions & roles but I am getting the below error:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied",

Below is my policy file and I have assigned the associated role in Lambda function execution role. Any pointers on what I am missing here, would be really helpful. Thanks.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutAccessPointConfigurationForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:DeleteAccessPoint",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:DeleteAccessPointForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetStorageLensConfigurationTagging",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetIntelligentTieringConfiguration",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:CreateMultiRegionAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetJobTagging",
                "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:InitiateReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:DescribeMultiRegionAccessPointOperation",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:DescribeJob",
                "s3:PutBucketLogging",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetAccessPointForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetStorageLensDashboard",
                "s3:CreateAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyForObjectLambda",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAttributes",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyStatus",
                "s3:UpdateJobPriority",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicyStatus",
                "s3:PutIntelligentTieringConfiguration",
                "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicy",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyStatusForObjectLambda",
                "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:DeleteMultiRegionAccessPoint",
                "s3:UpdateJobStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetAccessPointConfigurationForObjectLambda",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:CreateAccessPointForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicy",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bukcet-name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Regards,
Dbeings

Comment: Do you have slash and wildcard at the end of the Resource `arn:aws:s3:::<my-bukcet-name>/*`?

Answer (score 2):

Some actions operate on Buckets, eg `PutBucketWebsite`.

Some actions operate on Objects, eg `PutObject`.

To allow both of these operations you can use:

```json
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>",
              "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>/*"
            ]
```

The `/*` says "for any object in the bucket".